# Custom linux startup file in /etc/init.d/ failing on startup

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I'm am newish to linux, and I am trying to write a simple bash script to load on startup. All it does is send my IP to my website, since I'm on a DHCP network and I want to get the local network of my IP to ssh it when I'm on the same network. Anyway, this code works just fine as just a bash script, but when I try to put it in startup I keep getting the following error in startup:

```
[FAIL] startpar: service(s) returned failure: UpdateIP ... failed!
```

I'm not sure how to fix this. All my code is the following (Named UpdateIP), and I'm on a Raspberry Pi:

```
#!/bin/sh

IP_ADDR=$(ifconfig eth0 | sed -rn 's/^.*inet addr:(([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+).*$/\1/p')
wget -q -O /dev/null http://example.com/private/RPi_IP.php?send=${IP_ADDR}
```

Like I said, it works great alone as a bash script. I'm not sure how to make it work on startup. Any ideas?

Comment: What debugging have you performed?

Comment: I have been able to get the script to run alone, but startup I have no clue what's going on. I also don't have experience with linux much, I'm not sure what debugging I can do. I guess I haven't done much debugging. All I know is it works when it's not on startup.

Comment: Does Raspberry Pi have log files under `/var/log`? There may be more details there. Also, when you start up, the PATH is likely different, so maybe it can't find `wget` in the path? You could try using a full path name, like `/usr/bin/wget` or whatever it happens to be.

Comment: I tried your suggestions, /var/log only had logs of me editing the file since I used sudo. And /usr/bin/ is where wget is located so I modified that in the script, but it still won't work on startup. It works perfect if I just go ./UpdateIP in the terminal, but I can only do that after I login, which defeats the purpose

Comment: Does Raspberry Pi have a file named `/etc/rc.local` ?

Comment: Yes, it has /ect/rc.local . Should I modify this code?